# Refer to slicer-filtered table in DAX calculated column

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm beginning to think that what I'm looking for isn't actually possible.

I have two datasets - one of Titles and one of Keywords. Only one column from each is relevant to this query - Titles[Title] and Keywords[Keyword]. So pretty straightforward data. Titles has around 2 million rows, and Keywords will eventually have ~500-1000.

I would like to display a slicer of Keywords[Keyword] values, which will filter the Titles dataset where Titles[Title] contains one of the selected Keywords[Keyword] values.

I tried creating a DAX calculated column on Titles like below -

```
Matches = IF(SUMX(FILTER('Keywords','Keywords'[Keyword] <> ""),FIND(UPPER('Keywords'[Keyword]), UPPER(Titles[Title]),,0)) > 0,1, 0)
```

I then apply a report level filter for Matches >= 1. This works for **all** keyword values, but is not aware of the selection in the slicer.

I tried changing it to use ALLSELECTED('Keywords'[Keyword]) as the first argument passted to FILTER, but this doesn't seem to have any effect.

As a test, I created a Calculated Column and a Measure with the exact same DAX -

```
CONCATENATEX(VALUES(Keywords[Keyword]), Keywords[Keyword], ",")
```

This displays the slicer selection delimited by commas for the measure, but not for the column. Since I want to calculate this per row and filter the report based on this, a measure isn't suitable.

Is there any other way I can refer to the filtered Keywords[Keyword] in my calculated column? Or is there a way that a Measure could actually be used to achieve this? Or is there a completely different approach that I could try?

Comment: Columns are calculated once, when the model is loaded, and their values are not affected by slicers. If their value have to be affected by slicers/filtering, then you must use measures. I will recommend you to read [Measure vs Calculated Column: The Mysterious Question? Not!](https://radacad.com/measure-vs-calculated-column-the-mysterious-question-not).

Comment: add data if possible.

Comment: Have you tried that as a measure?

Comment: @GregGalloway It doesn't work as a measure as it's needs to be calculated for every row (and needs to be used as a report level filter - I don't believe measures can do that)

Comment: @JamesMacGilp create your Matches calculation as a measure, put Title on rows and Keyword as a slicer. Then make Matches > 0 a visual level filter on the Title table.